# Build Failed Cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, html-framework-7

I am trying to build a Framework7 app with Cordova-build-android 
but I am getting errors.

All the variables are set up correctly and I use NVM to manage my node versions.

Here is the error log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build-cordova-android' ]
2 info using npm@5.6.0
3 info using node@v8.9.4
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild-cordova-android',
4 verbose run-script   'build-cordova-android',
4 verbose run-script   'postbuild-cordova-android' ]
5 info lifecycle myapp@1.0.0~prebuild-cordova-android: myapp@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle myapp@1.0.0~build-cordova-android: myapp@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle myapp@1.0.0~build-cordova-android: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle myapp@1.0.0~build-cordova-android: PATH: C:\Users\CONRAD\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.9.4\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\CONRAD\test\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command;%NVM_HOME%;%NVM_SYMLINK%;C:\Users\CONRAD\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\CONRAD\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\CONRAD\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs
9 verbose lifecycle myapp@1.0.0~build-cordova-android: CWD: C:\Users\CONRAD\test
10 silly lifecycle myapp@1.0.0~build-cordova-android: Args: [ '/d /s /c',
10 silly lifecycle   'node ./build/build.js && cd cordova && cordova build android' ]
11 silly lifecycle myapp@1.0.0~build-cordova-android: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle myapp@1.0.0~build-cordova-android: Failed to exec build-cordova-android script
13 verbose stack Error: myapp@1.0.0 build-cordova-android: `node ./build/build.js && cd cordova && cordova build android`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\CONRAD\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.9.4\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:285:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\CONRAD\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.9.4\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
14 verbose pkgid myapp@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\CONRAD\test
16 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7600
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build-cordova-android"
18 verbose node v8.9.4
19 verbose npm  v5.6.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error myapp@1.0.0 build-cordova-android: `node ./build/build.js && cd cordova && cordova build android`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the myapp@1.0.0 build-cordova-android script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: If you did everything correctly, surely it must be the fault of the software. If you are not so sure, maybe share the problematic code.

Comment: I solved the issue

Comment: Thanks for the advise though

Comment: Either write an answer that describes your solution or delete the question. It cannot help anybody as it stands.